# Why doesn't Test-Path with -NewerThan work here

Tags: powershell

The file I'm looking for clearly exists

```
PS> Get-Item $Template|?{$_.LastWriteTime -gt $cutofftime}

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        9/10/2019   8:45 AM        1543608 Found.txt
```

Yet when I try to determine existence like this I get False.

```
PS> Test-Path $Template -NewerThan $cutofftime
False
```

And it's clearly due to the time rather than the file itself.

```
PS> Test-Path $Template
True
```

Anyone know why?

In case it matters:

```
$CutoffTime = (Get-Item OtherFile.txt).LastWriteTime
```

and

```
PS> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.16299.1146
PSEdition                      Desktop     
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.16299.1146
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0         
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: Does `$Template` resolves to exactly one item?

Comment: No.  $Template represents the collection of files, the newest of which being the one I want to know if it's newer than the one I've already got.

Comment: I spent almost an hour stepping thru every part of this.  I looked at the value of $cutoff which was obviously OK given the ?{filter} method uses it and it works there!  It doesn't make sense to me either but it doesn't work for me in my function or interactively at the 64bit IDE prompt.  I didn't try other execution environments or other hardware.

Comment: I'm confused.  If $template were an array, test-path would also return an array of booleans.

Comment: I misworded my comment. $Template contains wildcards and so it can match multiple files but it's not an array itself.

Answer (score 2):

If it's not a typo, then I can't explain it.  It works for me, if $template is correct.

EDIT:  Ok, I confirm the bug, if $template is set to 'f*.txt'.  Might have to run this twice.  I think the wildcard pattern might match the other file?  You could do sleep 1.

```
echo hi > otherfile.txt
sleep 60
echo hi > found.txt # newer

$template = 'f*.txt'
$CutoffTime = (Get-Item OtherFile.txt).LastWriteTime
$CutoffTime

Get-Item $Template|?{$_.LastWriteTime -gt $cutofftime} | ft

Test-Path $Template -NewerThan $cutofftime  # incorrectly false

Test-Path $Template
```

Output:

```
Friday, September 13, 2019 10:30:13 AM



    Directory: C:\users\admin\foo

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         9/13/2019 10:31 AM              4 found.txt

False
True
```

Comment: That underscore vs dash was a typo.   The original code was shortened. The variable contained a time about 5 minutes before the file being examined's time.

Comment: To match my conditions exactly you would need to use $template = '\*f\*.txt'.  Unfortunately, even with this change, your code worked on my machine too.  So I'm even more confused because that means it has something to do with the specific files I'm examining.  They do have much longer names and have non-alphanumeric characters but that really shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: I think I've found it.  Try your script again with Sleep 5.  (with or without wildcards I get the aberrant effect)

Comment: The sleep time didn't matter to me, but the bug definitely happened with a wildcard in the path, even in powershell 6.  What do you think, @mklement0?

Answer (score 0):

At least in my case, it appears that both LastWriteTime and the -NewerThan value undergo some amount of rounding before being compared.  I've not investigated enough to tell exactly how much but the effect I'm seeing is far more likely to occur when the time between the two values is short (2 minutes or less).  At differences of only a couple seconds it always happens.  At least on my machine.